# .vimrc does not working as expected

Tags: vim, vimrc, syntax-highlighting

I've been trying new color schemes and I set:

```
   colorscheme gotham256
   set background=dark
   set t_Co=256
   highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE
   highlight nonText ctermbg=NONE
```

but these thing doesn't work , actually these changing some color stuff but when I command manual like :set background=dark it works totally different.

For Instance I open new file my background doesn't change as set *background=dark* and my terminal default color stays.

If I command manually step by step like

```
colorscheme gotham256
set background=dark
set t_Co=256
```

It is working the way I want.

Why Is this happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: Do you source some other settings file after those lines?

Comment: I have some setting but they doesn't connected each other any way if you are asking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your .vimrc like so with a colon before the commands

```
:colorscheme gotham256
:set background=dark
:set t_Co=256
:highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE
:highlight nonText ctermbg=NONE
```

Comment: This is not incorrect this fixed my problem thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! Some systems do not interpret the commands without a colon. My machine works both ways, but some do not. Glad I could help you fix your problem!

Comment: @dotancohen why incorrect? it seems to work...

Comment: I'm not sure to what I was referring to two years ago, probably to the colons, so I simply removed my comment.